# Update autocomplete GRASS GIS console

Tags: grass-gis, layers

I am writing a lot of commands in the GRASS GIS console and I get suggestions for auto-complete, i.e. for mapset and layer names.

Unfortunately, this works for layers and mapsets that are already in the location when I first start GRASS GIS. If I create a new layer or mapset it will never show in the auotcomplete suggestions until I restart GRASS GIS.

Is there a way to "refresh" the autocomplete list?

Comment: Please open a feature or bug report (you decide) here: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues Then the GUI developers may give some suggestion - they are likely not reading here.

Comment: great thanks. Anyway, I'll update the post as soon as they answer to me!